# Laravel nova: how to define belongsTo option value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

Right now by setting up belongsTo relation in laravel nova resource I am getting option values as ID's, but instead I need plan_service_id and I am not sure how to achieve this...
Code:

**Nova TeamSubscriptionResource:**

```
public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            BelongsTo::make('Plan', 'plan', 'App\Nova\Plan')->display('name'),
        ];
    }
```

**Plan model:**

```
public function teamSubscriptions()
    {   
        return $this->hasMany('App\TeamSubscription', 'stripe_plan', 'plan_service_id');
    }
```

**TeamSubscription model:**

```
public function plan() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Plan', 'stripe_plan', 'plan_service_id');
    }
}
```

Current result option value is filled with $plan->id:

[current html result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbUvV.png)

Result wanted, option value should be filled with $plan->plan_service_id:

[wanted html result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4ZcX.png)

Comment: Welcome. Is the html result the actual outcome? If yes, then what does a successful outcome look like.?

Comment: @Tedinoz Yes it is an html outcome, it should be something like this: [image](https://i.imgur.com/H3uFdFw.png)

Comment: By the way the option values in last image are from $plan->plan_service_id and I want to specify that TeamSubscriptionResource would use it instead of $plan->id as option value.

Comment: Ernesta, the new image and following comment are very valuable. You should edit your question to include this information - it makes it easier for people to access rather than having to read through the comments.